# I am trying to remove the last letter of a string from one cell to the next in excel

Tags: excel, string, parsing, trim

Here is the scenario, I am in excel and I am trying to move the middle initial from one cell to the next but only some of the cells have middle initials which is the last letter in the cell and it may be accompanied by a period. Cell A1 maybe consist of value "Betty", "Betty B" , or "BEtty B."

I have a empty column B and I am trying to extract the middle initial from cell `A1` meaning if it has only "Betty" it doesnt need to extract the y but it is BEtty B or Betty B. it needs to take the B , you can have the B. I will remove the period later

Here is my attempt for cell `B1` i put `=RIGHT(a1, len(a1)-find(" ", a1))` but it only brings back the full name from `A1`.

Comment: Would you only have first names without any space before any possible middle name initial? Meaning, only if a space exists in your column you would want to extract what's behind that space?

Comment: yess that is it

Comment: Please can you clarify with some sample input and expected output? From your comments on the answers, your OP doesn't match what you're trying to actually do.

Comment: It sounds like you have a leading space in your cells.  Give this a try: `=MID(TRIM(A1),FIND(" ",TRIM(A1)&" ")+1,1)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, you can use `SUBSTITUTE()` to check if the length of the cell is the same as without:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")),"",MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,1))
```

Assuming you will only have `NAME X` where `X` is a single initial.

Or:

```
=IF(--ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",A1)),MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1)+1,1),"")
```

Result of first formula:

[image]

Comment: this only extract the first letter not the last character , i need the last in "Ashley T."  I need "T." in a new column

Comment: @AustinHolmes - Can you please clarify then? Per your OP, `I am trying to extract the middle initial from cell A1 meaning if it has only "Betty" it doesnt need to extract the y but it is BEtty B or Betty B. it needs to take the B , you can have the B. I will remove the period later` - the formulas do just that.

Comment: yeah im copyin the codes and putting them in excel they dont work, maybe its my excel oh well thanks anyways

Comment: @AustinHolmes you're copying and pasting the names in to excel? Perhaps there are extra characters we're not considering.  Can you post some sample data?